# How to select all following elements with class in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I select all following elements from my selector, stopping when the next element is not part of it and ignoring the further elements?

example:

```
<div class="primary"></div>
  <div class="sub"></div>
  <div class="sub"></div>
  <div class="sub"></div>
<div class="primary"></div>
 <div class="sub"></div>
<div class="primary"></div>
 <div class="sub"></div>
 <div class="sub"></div>
```

now in js / jquery:

```
$('.primary').click(function()
{
$(this)....  //acces to all following elements with class "sub"
});
```

so when clicking on the first primary div, I can affect the 3 following "sub" divs
I know I could do some kind of .next() in a while, but this seams inefficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [.nextUntil()](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/)

```
$('.primary').click(function(){
    $(this).nextUntil('.primary').text($(this).text())
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/afCpM/)

Comment: so easy! I tried finding this one without success, happy it exists. Why didn't I find this... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This will Helpful to you

`**SEE DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/dhaval17/W3Jsy/**`